# How would you check if property name(s) from one object exist in another?

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I am trying to transfer/copy properties from object1 to object2, but only properties that are undefined in object2.

Thanks in advance, I hope this comes across clearly!

```html
let object1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 } 
let object2 = { a: 'string' }

fillObj = function (object2, object1) {
  for (let key in object1) {
    if (typeof object2.key === undefined) {
      object2[key] = object1[key];
    } 
  }
  return object2; //should return {a: 'string', b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
};
```

Comment: Use bracket notation instead of dot notation to look up a variable property name

Comment: that still  only returns object2 as { a: 'string' }  in the above code.

Comment: You also need to either remove the `typeof`, or use `=== 'undefined'`, since `typeof` resolves to a string, never to `undefined`

Comment: thanks for your patience. I actually tried that earlier, and tests come through except for a fail on "ignore the object prototype".  Any tips or explanation for this?

Comment: Use `hasOwnProperty` to check to see if the *instance object* has the property - it'll ignore inherited properties. As an inelegant shorthand, you could also spread the object first before continuing with the code.

Comment: I'm struggling to see where to implement that to make the code work as intended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224993/discussion-between-mathias-sode-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Look properties on an object by a variable property name by using bracket notation, not dot notation

(2) To check if something is undefined, either compare against undefined directly, or use `typeof` and compare against the *string* `'undefined'` (but this check isn't needed for this algorithm)

(3) Make sure the properties are *own properties*, not inherited properties, with `hasOwnProperty`

```js
let object1 = { a: 'string' } 
let object2 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }

fillObj = function (object2, object1) {
  for (let key in object1) {
    if (object1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      object2[key] = object1[key];
    } 
  }
  return object2; //should return {a: 'string', b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
};

console.log(fillObj(object2, object1));
```

Or use `Object.entries`, which iterates over own-properties only:

```js
let object1 = { a: 'string' } 
let object2 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }

fillObj = function (object2, object1) {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    object2[key] = val;
  }
  return object2; //should return {a: 'string', b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
};

console.log(fillObj(object2, object1));
```